# CSS Rendering After HTML

Tags: html, css, wordpress, pagespeed

I'm having an issue that my website is rendering CSS after a second or so of the HTML, so there's basically a white unstyled page that appears for a second before the styles render. The problem is worse on FireFox. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Sounds like you're loading css at the end of your html instead of the beginning, or your css file is massive.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Brian. It's a Wordpress site with numerous plugins involved so I'm thinking the size of the .css might be the issue. I tried using this site (https://www.sitelocity.com/critical-path-css-generator) to generate critical css and inserting into the head, but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with wordpress to know how to implement this, but I did have a similar problem with Laravel. After some reading and developing I came up with this. It works great.

Place this in te head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.documentElement.style.opacity = 0;
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        document.documentElement.classList.add("showhtml");
    });
</script>
```

Create a CSS entry:

```
html.showhtml {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
```

What it does is forcing the page to render with an opacity of 0 on the HTML-tag. After loading the added listener 'load' jumps into action and adds the CSS class `showhtml` to the HTMl-tag. The CSS then animates the pages to an opacity of 1.
It is a graceful solution where you can control the speed of the animation, and you page will also show in case somebody have their javascript turned off.

Comment: Wow, thank you Daniel this solved the issue. As I suspected, the CSS file is large on my site and takes a while to load in the first place, so I do see a blank white screen for a moment before the fully rendered page appears - but it's better than seeing plain HTML. For whatever reason the delay is a lot longer on FireFox than Chrome or even Safari but regardless I'm satisfied with this fix.

Comment: The delay has to do with the loading, the render engine of the browser how it handles the cache in speed. All the script does is wait for the moment the html is loaded and then perform the animation. This should be the same for all browsers. In the example the animation is very short. But the loading itself depends on other elements like mentioned.